# Svn change directory

Tags: svn

I want to change the directory where I add files using svn. I tried

```
svn switch --relocate https://old_directory https://new_directory
```

It runs with no error but when I do `svn info` the URL is still the old one (actually it looks like *svn+ssh://old_directory* instead of *https://old_directory*).
I also tried

```
 svn switch --relocate `svn+ssh://old_directory svn+ssh://new_directory`
```

but I get this message `svn: Relocate can only change the repository part of an URL` and still nothing changes.

Please can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: What's the `git` tag for when the question is about svn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the --relocate switch, that switch is actually deprecated if you're using a more recent version of svn.

Simply navigating to your checked out directory in the command line and calling `svn switch https://new_directory` should fix the issue.

Now, if it's the same directory but the URL has changed, that's a completely different story. Then you'd want to use `svn relocate`. Again you'd have to navigate to the directory (cd) via the command line and run:

```
svn relocate https://new_directory
```

[Here is a quote from redbean](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html) that helps me understand the difference. Judging by your wording in the first sentence it sounds like you just want to change directories, but in the chance that I didn't interpret it correctly, here is the svn's explanation:

> Users often get confused about the difference between svn switch and svn relocate. Here's the rule of thumb:
>
> If the working copy needs to reflect a new directory within the repository, use svn switch.
>
> If the working copy still reflects the same repository directory, but the location of the repository itself has changed, use svn relocate.